Not Averaging Gamma and Beta Gradients in BatchNormalization leads me to higher accuracy
I'm implementing batchnorm from scratch in pure NumPy.
I noticed something interesting.
While I'm calculating the gradients of gamma (dg) and beta (db), ignoring the summation / averaging of the gradients for specifically gamma and beta, leads me to faster convergence while not doing so leads to slower training.
Here's how I'm initializing my parameters
def init_params():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed = 1)
    w1 = rng.normal(size = (32, 784)) * np.sqrt(1/784)
    g1 = np.ones((32, 1))
    b1 = np.zeros((32, 1))
    w2 = rng.normal(size = (10 ,32)) * np.sqrt(1/ 784)
    g2 = np.ones((10, 1))
    b2 = np.zeros((10 ,1))
    return w1, g1, b1, w2, g2, b2


Here, I don't average the gradients for gamma (dg) and beta (db):
def backward(x, one_hot, a2, a1, w2, b_z2_norm, b_z1_norm, z1_norm, g2, g1, std2, std1):
    eps = 1e-8

    ''' Layer 2 Backprop '''

    dz2_norm = a2 - one_hot #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    dg2 = dz2_norm * b_z2_norm  #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    db2 = dz2_norm  #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    dz2 = dz2_norm * g2 * (1 / np.abs(std2 + eps)) #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    dw2 = np.dot(dz2, a1.T) / x.shape[1] #  #(10, (60000 / batch_size) • (60000 / batch_size, 32)) -> 10, 32

    ''' Layer 1 Backprop'''

    dz1_norm = np.dot(w2.T, dz2) * leaky_relu_deriv(z1_norm) # ( (32, 10) • (10, 60000 / batch_size)) -> 32, 6000
    dg1 = dz1_norm * b_z1_norm  # 32, (60000 / batch_size)
    db1 = dz1_norm # 32, (60000 / batch_size)
    dz1 = dz1_norm * g1 * (1 / np.abs(std1 + eps)) # 32, (60000 / batch_size)
    dw1 = np.dot(dz1, x.T) / x.shape[1] # ( (32, (60000 / batch_size)) • (60000 / batch_size, 784)) -> 32, 784
return dw2, dg2, db2, dw1, dg1, db1

def update(w2, g2, b2, w1, g1, b1, dw2, dg2, db2, dw1, dg1, db1, sdw1, sdg1, sdb1, sdw2, sdg2, sdb2, vdw1, vdg1, vdb1, vdw2, vdg2, vdb2, alpha, beta1, beta2):

    eps = 1e-8

    '''

    Computing EWAs of the gradients

    '''

    vdw1 = (beta1 * vdw1) + (1 - beta1) * dw1
    vdg1 = (beta1 * vdg1) + (1 - beta1) * dg1
    vdb1 = (beta1 * vdb1) + (1 - beta1) * db1

    vdw2 = (beta1 * vdw2) + (1 - beta1) * dw2
    vdg2 = (beta1 * vdg2) + (1 - beta1) * dg2
    vdb2 = (beta1 * vdb2) + (1 - beta1) * db2

    '''

    Computing EWAs based on squared gradients.

    '''

    sdw1 = (beta2 * sdw1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dw1)
    sdg1 = (beta2 * sdg1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dg1)
    sdb1 = (beta2 * sdb1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(db1)

    sdw2 = (beta2 * sdw2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dw2)
    sdg2 = (beta2 * sdg2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dg2)
    sdb2 = (beta2 * sdb2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(db2)


    '''

    Adam's Update rule

    '''

    w2 = w2 - (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdw2 + eps))) * vdw2
    g2 = g2 - (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdg2 + eps))) * vdg2
    b2 = b2 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdb2 + eps))) * vdb2
    w1 = w1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdw1 + eps))) * vdw1
    g1 = g1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdg1 + eps))) * vdg1
    b1 = b1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdb1 + eps))) * vdb1
    return w2, g2, b2, w1, g1, b1, sdw1, sdg1, sdb1, sdw2, sdg2, sdb2, vdw1, vdg1, vdb1, vdw2, vdg2, vdb2,


I happen to get above 95% accuracy in about 250 epochs.
Here, I do average the gradients for gamma and beta:
def backward(x, one_hot, a2, a1, w2, b_z2_norm, b_z1_norm, z1_norm, g2, g1, std2, std1):
    eps = 1e-8

    ''' Layer 2 Backprop '''

    dz2_norm = a2 - one_hot #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    dg2 = np.sum(dz2_norm * b_z2_norm, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / x.shape[1]
    db2 = np.sum(dz2_norm, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / x.shape[1]
    dz2 = dz2_norm * g2 * (1 / np.abs(std2 + eps)) #10, (60000 / batch_size)
    dw2 = np.dot(dz2, a1.T) / x.shape[1] #  #(10, (60000 / batch_size) • (60000 / batch_size, 32)) -> 10, 32

    ''' Layer 1 Backprop'''

    dz1_norm = np.dot(w2.T, dz2) * leaky_relu_deriv(z1_norm) # ( (32, 10) • (10, 60000 / batch_size)) -> 32, 6000
    dg1 = np.sum(dz1_norm * b_z1_norm, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / x.shape[1]
    db1 = np.sum(dz1_norm, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
    dz1 = dz1_norm * g1 * (1 / np.abs(std1 + eps)) # 32, (60000 / batch_size)
    dw1 = np.dot(dz1, x.T) / x.shape[1] # ( (32, (60000 / batch_size)) • (60000 / batch_size, 784)) -> 32, 784

    return dw2, dg2, db2, dw1, dg1, db1

def update(w2, g2, b2, w1, g1, b1, dw2, dg2, db2, dw1, dg1, db1, sdw1, sdg1, sdb1, sdw2, sdg2, sdb2, vdw1, vdg1, vdb1, vdw2, vdg2, vdb2, alpha, beta1, beta2):

    eps = 1e-8

    '''

    Computing EWAs of the gradients

    '''

    vdw1 = (beta1 * vdw1) + (1 - beta1) * dw1
    vdg1 = (beta1 * vdg1) + (1 - beta1) * dg1
    vdb1 = (beta1 * vdb1) + (1 - beta1) * db1

    vdw2 = (beta1 * vdw2) + (1 - beta1) * dw2
    vdg2 = (beta1 * vdg2) + (1 - beta1) * dg2
    vdb2 = (beta1 * vdb2) + (1 - beta1) * db2

    '''

    Computing EWAs based on squared gradients.

    '''

    sdw1 = (beta2 * sdw1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dw1)
    sdg1 = (beta2 * sdg1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dg1)
    sdb1 = (beta2 * sdb1) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(db1)

    sdw2 = (beta2 * sdw2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dw2)
    sdg2 = (beta2 * sdg2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(dg2)
    sdb2 = (beta2 * sdb2) + (1 - beta2) * np.square(db2)


    '''

    Adam's Update rule

    '''

    w2 = w2 - (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdw2 + eps))) * vdw2
    g2 = g2 - (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdg2 + eps))) * vdg2
    b2 = b2 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdb2 + eps))) * vdb2
    w1 = w1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdw1 + eps))) * vdw1
    g1 = g1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdg1 + eps))) * vdg1
    b1 = b1 -  (alpha / (np.sqrt(sdb1 + eps))) * vdb1
    return w2, g2, b2, w1, g1, b1, sdw1, sdg1, sdb1, sdw2, sdg2, sdb2, vdw1, vdg1, vdb1, vdw2, vdg2, vdb2,

I'm curious to know why the former gives me better results than the latter.
I doesn't seem sensical to me because I'd figure that the dimensions of the gradients had to match the dimensions of the original parameters.
But of course, not taking the sum / average of them, doens't make the dimensions equivalent yet still works and gives me faster convergence.

please upload only the relevant code, nobody will read all of that... apart from that, "ignoring the summation / averaging of the gradients" you mean not updating them aka keeping always the same gamma and beta from the beginning to the end?
